# understanding recursive call logic in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have scenario where nested function call do recursive call to parent function.

In below code `rule_four_question` function again makes call to `linkage`. So what I expect is all facts for `linkage` should be considered again.

pseudo code:

```
sentence(LINK,LINKSTART,LINKEND)
{
if(LINK == 'Xx')
    //that mean sentence has two subsentences.
    //Now check both sentence. The sentence having link == `Wq` that is question based sent
    //So identifying whether subsentences are question or not
else
    //Sentence is single query
}
```

}

What I want to do it.
if `link = Wq or Ws or W*` then asign rule `one`

If `link = Xx` then we have two sentence, so now need to check links in both sentences. If `REND` of child link is `<` `REND` of parent and any condition matches then rule `three` and check for `rule four`

ISsue is.

Nested call to `linkage` does not call or `facts` mentioned in header. Nested call only considers `Ws` not the `Wq`

```
linkage('Ws', 2, 3, 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false','false').
linkage('Xx', 1, 9, 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false','false').
linkage('Wq', 10, 13, 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false','false').
/*
linkage('Ws', '2', '3', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false','false').
linkage('Cv', '4', '6', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false','false').
*/

rule_first_question(LINK, LEND, REND):-
(
    (
        member(LINK, ['Xx']),
        nb_linkval(rule, 'two')
    )
    ; (
        nb_linkval(rule, 'one')
    )
).

rule_four_question(LINK, LEND, REND, ISMULTIPLE, LINKONE, LINKTWO, LINKONEISQUERY, LINKTWOISQUERY,R):-
(
    writeln('parent'),
    writeln(LINK),
    (
        linkage(LINK2, LEND2, REND2, ISMULTIPLE2, LINKONE2, LINKTWO2, LINKONEISQUERY2, LINKTWOISQUERY2,R2) ->
                (
                    writeln('child'),
                    writeln(LINK2),
                    REND > REND2 ->
                    (
                        write('First sentence is query'),
                        member(LINK, ['Wq']),
                        nb_linkval(rule, 'three')
                    )
                    ; (
                        member(LINK, ['Wj']),
                        nb_linkval(rule, 'three')
                    )
                    ; (
                        member(LINK, ['Ws']),
                        nb_linkval(rule, 'three')
                    )
                    ; (
                        member(LINK, ['Qd']),
                        nb_linkval(rule, 'three')
                    ),
                        (
                            REND < REND2 ->
                            (
                                write('SEcond sentence is query'),
                                member(LINK, ['Wq']),
                                nb_linkval(rule, 'four')
                            )
                            ; (
                                member(LINK, ['Wj']),
                                nb_linkval(rule, 'four')
                            )
                            ; (
                                member(LINK, ['Ws']),
                                nb_linkval(rule, 'four')
                            )
                            ; (
                                member(LINK, ['Qd']),
                                nb_linkval(rule, 'four')
                            );
                            nb_linkval(rule, 'two')
                        )

               )
    )
).

/*
if rule three then say first sentence is quetion, 2nd not
if rule four then say both sentence are question
if rule two then say none of sentence
if rule one then say only one sentence and that is the query
*/
question(LINK, LEND, REND , ISMULTIPLE, LINKONE, LINKTWO, LINKONEISQUERY, LINKTWOISQUERY,RULE):-
    linkage(LINK, LEND, REND, ISMULTIPLE, LINKONE, LINKTWO, LINKONEISQUERY, LINKTWOISQUERY,R),
    (
        (
            rule_first_question(LINK, LEND, REND) ->
            nb_getval(rule, RULE),
            (
                RULE = 'one' ->
                    writeln('\n'),
                    writeln(LINK),
                    writeln(RULE)
                ;
                    (
                        RULE = 'two' ->
                            writeln('\n'),
                            writeln(LINK),
                            writeln(RULE),
                            rule_four_question(LINK, LEND, REND, ISMULTIPLE, LINKONE, LINKTWO, LINKONEISQUERY, LINKTWOISQUERY,R) ->
                                nb_getval(rule, RULE),
                                writeln(RULE)
                        ;
                        writeln('nothing')
                    )
            )
        )
    ).
```

output :

```
1 ?- question(LINK, LEND, REND , ISMULTIPLE, LINKONE, LINKTWO, LINKONEISQUERY, LINKTWOISQUERY,RULE).


Ws
one
LINK = 'Ws',
LEND = 2,
REND = 3,
ISMULTIPLE = LINKONE, LINKONE = LINKTWO, LINKTWO = LINKONEISQUERY, LINKONEISQUERY = LINKTWOISQUERY, LINKTWOISQUERY = false,
RULE = one ;


Xx
two
parent
Xx
child
Ws
First sentence is query #here next I expect answer for second sentence too, that is not coming

Wq
one
LINK = 'Wq',
LEND = 10,
REND = 13,
ISMULTIPLE = LINKONE, LINKONE = LINKTWO, LINKTWO = LINKONEISQUERY, LINKONEISQUERY = LINKTWOISQUERY, LINKTWOISQUERY = false,
RULE = one.
```

Comment: This is a well-meaning comment, so I hope you read it as such: your Prolog is so far from the way that Prolog is normally used that I don't even feel like reading through your code. Global variables, deeply nested if-elses, long predicates with side effects and non-descriptive names....

Comment: @Boris: thank, I will try to improve this. But as such this is my first prolog program, I could not really follow the standards.

Comment: One thing you could do is tell us what problem you are trying to solve (described in pseudo-code or just free text), give a working solution, and ask how it can be improved. At the moment, one can only guess what you are trying to get at.

Comment: @Boris: thanks, issue solved. I took `->` condition statement rather `,` for loop in code.

Comment: quick syntax note: ... 'false' = false ...

Comment: @Boris: I added pseodo code. I appreciate if you can help in improving the code. Let me know if any further details required